# Use Pythons argparse to make an argument being a flag or accepting a parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am using `argparse` in Python 3. My requirement is to support the following 3 use-cases:

```
$ python3 foo.py --test       <== results e.g. in True
$ python3 foo.py --test=foo   <== results in foo
$ python3 foo.py              <== results in arg.test is None or False
```

I found `store_true`, and `store`, but can't find any configuration where I can achieve the following arg list as mentioned above. Either it wants to have a parameter, or None. Both seems not to work. Is there any way to make a argument optional?

Comment: Don't understand *results*, and what is different between 1&3 ?

Comment: `nargs='?'` marks the argument as optional. The example given in [the nargs examples[](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) seems to match what you're attempting to do - as soon as you clear up the confusion about example 1 & 3.

Comment: `nargs='?'` plus `default` and `const` values should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nargs='?'` to make the argument optional, `const=True` for when the flag is given with no argument, and `default=False` for when the flag is not given.

Here's the explanation and an example from the documentation on [`nargs='?'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs):

> `'?'`. One argument will be consumed from the command line if possible, and produced as a single item. If no command-line argument is present, the value from [default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#default) will be produced. Note that for optional arguments, there is an additional case - the option string is present but not followed by a command-line argument. In this case the value from [const](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#const) will be produced. Some examples to illustrate this:
>
> ```
> >>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
> >>> parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='?', const='c', default='d')
> >>> parser.add_argument('bar', nargs='?', default='d')
> >>> parser.parse_args(['XX', '--foo', 'YY'])
> Namespace(bar='XX', foo='YY')
> >>> parser.parse_args(['XX', '--foo'])
> Namespace(bar='XX', foo='c')
> >>> parser.parse_args([])
> Namespace(bar='d', foo='d')
> ```